# get cropped image to display in a new canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display a croppped area in a new canvas. But I am stuck at getImageData line. I get the values x,y ,tx,ty correctly since I tested them out with alerts. But the getImageData line isnt working also with what I have written , will I be able to display the croppped image in the new canvas? Thank you

```
var x = $("#crop_square").width();
var y = $("#crop_square").height();

var ty = $("#crop_square").offset().top - $("#area_c").offset().top;
var tx = $("#crop_square").offset().left - $("#area_c").offset().left;

var c = document.getElementById("area_c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var imageData = ctx.getImageData(x, y, tx, ty); // this line not working

var c2 = document.getElementById("area_c2");
var ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");
ctx2.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

Comment: That looks like it should work as far as I can tell. What values do you have for `x`, `y`, `tx`, and `ty`?

Comment: okay it is working , it should have been imageData = ctx.getImageData(tx, ty, x, y);